# Problema en la URL de API de Facebook

Tags: javascript

Tengo una web (HTML) que obtenía el Token de Acceso (de Facebook) de un usuario únicamente poniendo su correo y contraseña. Lo hago asignando ID a los inputs y de ahí mandarlos al JS.

Hasta hace poco funcionaba bien, pero ya no.

Este es el código:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
   var id = $('#id').val();
   var pass = $('#pass').val();
    var url = 'https://b-graph.facebook.com/auth/login?email=' + id + '&password=' + pass + '&access_token=6628568379|c1e620fa708a1d5696fb991c1bde5662&method=post';
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe.src = url;
    iframe.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
    $('#iframe').show();
});
```

**¿Cómo lo arreglo? Parece ser que esa URL ya no funciona.**

Sé muy poco de Javascript, ojalá pudiese proporcionarme la nueva URL :(

Que intente? Modificar la URL mediante los parámetros que establece FB, pero no le entendí.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/?locale=es_LA#usertokens

Comment: estas usando la API de FB?? también puedes leer [esto](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/?locale=es_LA#javascript)

Comment: Pues todo lo que ves en el código es lo que hacía funcionar el sitio :( No entiendo nada, solo quiero que funcione

Comment: Pon un pantallazo de lo que te arroja la consola de desarrolladores del Chrome